# LyX 2.1.4 does't load Document Classes after using Reconfigure

Tags: lyx, document-classes

I tried to add on the LyX (Windows 10) Layouts folder some .layouts, and after I run "Tools -> Reconfigure" and restarting LyX it doesn't neither the default classes.

How can I solve this problem? I already tried to disable "Install Missing Packages on-the-fly" on MikTeX 2.9 but still isn't able to load the classes.

[image: Missing default Document Classess]

Answer (score 1):

I solved this removing the new file I add in the LyX Layouts folder. So it looks like a bug. So I guess I must load "local layouts" every time.

Comment: Did you put the new file in the system LyX layouts folder or the user dir layouts folder? The user dir layouts folder is the correct place for user layouts. Also, what is the output of reconfigure? You should be able to see it in view > messages pane.

Comment: Hi, yes but even if I put the layout file in the user folder (App Data...) I still get the same error. To solve this problem: 1 - I removed the .layout file I am trying to use from the Layouts folders (both user and for all users). 2 - I run the Reconfigure and after restarting LyX, all the previous default document classes were add. 3 - To use the layout file that I want, on Lyx, I put the .layout file in the same folder I have my LyX file. 4 - Using the option "Local Layouts", I selected the .layout file, and now when I close and open the Lyx, I don't get any error. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I see. I hope that you can post this information as well as the output from the reconfigure, on a bug report at http://www.lyx.org/trac . The only way we can fix the bug is if we know about it and I've never heard of this one before.